# Mercurial Templating for hg serve

Tags: templates, mercurial, tortoisehg

So, I'm attempting to adjust the templates that the `hg serve` command use. I would like the date to be local time instead of relative time.

I've found several tutorials on how to create a template, and I've played around enough to figure out how to template `hg log`, `hg tip`, etc, but whenever I try with `hg serve`, I get a runtime error that "no hgweb templates were found".

Looking in my mercurial installation, the only place I'm finding hgweb referenced is in "C:\Program Files\TortoiseHg\lib\library.zip".

This seems like a pretty simple change to make! Where am I going wrong?